# Missing Buyer Address and name in GetOrder Method

Tags: amazon-mws

AddressLine1,2,3, and Name of Order object under GetOrder and ListOrders method dissapeared in calls since 2019-06-13.
When i call method ListOrders, there is no AddressLine1,AddressLine2,AddressLine3 and Name fields under Order->ShippingAddress

I'm using 2013-09-01 version.

This is the [thread](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/208254/addressline-of-order-object-under-listorders-metho.html?childToView=208504#answer-208504) in MWS Forum

Thanks!

```
<ShippingAddress>
   <City>Avellino</City>
//Missing fields
   <PostalCode>83100</PostalCode>
   <isAddressSharingConfidential>false</isAddressSharingConfidential>
   <StateOrRegion>Avellino</StateOrRegion>
   <CountryCode>IT</CountryCode>
</ShippingAddress>
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be raised to the Amazon MWS team, not stack overflow.

Comment: It is exactly i did, and if they answer i'll post solution here.

Comment: I have the same problem. I do not see a `BuyerName` field either.

Comment: Problem is solved now. Reason was Amazon needs you have "PII" level, i gained that level creating a ticket and inquiring from that in Amazon MWS user section, they sent me a form with security and privacy cuestions, i filled and in minutes, all solved.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problem is solved now. The issue was that Amazon needs you have "PII" level. I gained that level by creating a ticket and inquiring from that in the Amazon MWS user section, they sent me a form with security and privacy questions, which I filled out and in minutes it was all solved.